# Designing model/database for distance between any two locations (that may change)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

We should create a web app which has a number of events each with a location (created as user-generated content, so the number of events will be increasingly large).
The distance between any events should be available, for example to determine the top 5 closest events and such things. 
Users may change the locations of events.

How should one design the database/model for this (in a scalable way)?

I was thinking of doing it with a "distance table" (like so http://www.deutschland-tourist.info/images/entfernungstabelle.gif). Then every time, if a location changes, one row and one column have to be recalculated (this should be done with a delayed job, because it is not important to have the changes instantly). Possible problems in Scaling: Database to large (n² items for n events), too much calculation to be done. For example we should see if this is okay for 10.000 users. If each has created just one event, then this would be 100 million integers...

Do you think this would be a good way to do it efficiently? How could one realize such a distance table with an rails model? Is it possible with a SQL databse?
Would you start other approaches?

Comment: Do you require distances between multiple locations as shown in [distance table](http://www.deutschland-tourist.info/images/entfernungstabelle.gif) which will be difficult to implement. Or from one location to many which can be simple to implement

Comment: @Catcall About the suggestions to use another database type: How should it be done if this has to be linked into an existing project that works with a MySQL database? Is it okay to have different data base typed in one project? Should one migrate everything to, say PostgreSQL?

Comment: See Edited answer with 30 X 30 distance matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.1+ supports [kth nearest neighbor indexing](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#K-Nearest-Neighbor_Indexing). Something like this would *probably* give you the best performance using a SQL dbms, and it wouldn't require maintaining any additional tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a graph database as it's more natural fit to your problem. Take a look at [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org). There's even a nice ruby library to work with: [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography).

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link. Hope that will help you. 
https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived using PHP/MySQL with latidude/longditude coordinates.The [**Haversine Formula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is used to determine distance using these coordinates.

[image: 30 X 30 matrix] 
The [**demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/pdo/distancematrix.php) displaying distances on a 30 X 30 matrix like your example,and a [**demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) using to show railway stations on a map using this. The MySQL database structure is

```
id   | int(11)
name | varchar(200)
lat  | decimal(10,6)
lon  | decimal(10,6)
```

The SQL SELECT statement using Haversine Formula is

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM mytable ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 30");
// Assign parameters
$stmt->bindParam(1,$lat);//from search location
$stmt->bindParam(2,$lng);//from search location
$stmt->bindParam(3,$lat);// duplicate of parameter 1
```

The matix is generated from allays using the PHP function

```
function distanceHaversine($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  $deltaLat = $lat2 - $lat1 ;
  $deltaLon = $lon2 - $lon1 ;
  $earthRadius = 3959; // in miles 6371 in meters.
  $alpha    = $deltaLat/2;
  $beta     = $deltaLon/2;
  $a        = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
  $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
  $distance = 2 * $earthRadius * $c;
  $distance = round($distance, 4);

  return $distance;
}
```